# Word Add-in JS API: How to resize inline picture to paper size?

Tags: javascript, office-js, word-addins

I managed to add image to my header with

```
context.document.sections.getFirst().getHeader("primary").insertInlinePictureFromBase64(img, "Start");
```

However, no matter how big my picture is, it's always going to be readjusted automatically to fit within the default margin of the page.

So How do I enlarge the picture so that it's exactly the size of the paper (e.g. should be 8.5" x 11" for a letter size paper).
Thanks!

Comment: Use the `height` and `width` properties of the `InlinePicture`

Comment: Thank Cindy. I was under the impression that InlinePicture doesn't allow you to go over the margins.

Comment: I think I need a way to do this in OOXML, since floating image is not possible in JS, from what I gather.

Comment: Did you ever succeed with this?

Comment: @CindyMeister: Is there still a way to get document page width and height and margins in 2021?